# The Problem of variable referenced in the nested function

Tags: python-2.7, variables, nested-function, pythoninterpreter

There are tow simple functions owning nested function, as follows:

```
def a():
    abc = 1
    def write():
        print abc
    write()

def b():
    abc = 1
    def write():
        print abc
        abc += 1
    write()
```

The difference between these tow is just that I tried to change the value of the variable.

When I run a(),that's ok.

When I run b(),I get back the error  **"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'abc' referenced before assignment"**

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is in the scope of variables. The nested functions in your program have their own local namespace/scope different from the outer function that calls them.

According to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

> If a name is declared global, then all references and assignments go
>   directly to the middle scope containing the module’s global names.
>   Otherwise, all variables found outside of the innermost scope are
>   read-only (an attempt to write to such a variable will simply create a
>   new local variable in the innermost scope, leaving the identically
>   named outer variable unchanged).

Meaning that if you instead try this:

```
def b():
    abc = 1
    global abc
    print abc
    def write():
        global abc
        abc += 1
        print abc
    write()
    print abc
```

your function `b` will run without errors. This also means that the value of `abc` will increase globally and become `2` after calling `write()`.

If you don't declare your `abc` variable as `global`, it will be read-only for the nested function `write()`. `write()` won't be able to change it but it will be able to print it, or locally re-assign it. The following also works because it first reassigns the value of `abc` to another, local variable and then changes that variable,

```
def a():
    abc = 1
    def write():
        print abc
        abc2 = abc
        abc2 += 1
        print abc2
    write()
```

You can print local variables in a given scope using `print locals()`.

Comment: Glad to help! It was interesting.